# Why does C++11 fail to treat two template typenames T == U in constructor in a template class?

Tags: class, templates, c++11, copy-constructor, move-semantics

> I could not find a short and better title. :(

Suppose I have a **simple C++11 template class** definition as below:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    T v;
    A(){};
    template <typename U>
    A(const A<U>& a); // copy ctor
    A(A<T>&& a); // move ctor
};

template <typename T>
template <typename U>
A<T>::A(const A<U>& a) // copy ctor
{
    v = a.v;
}

template <typename T> // move ctor
A<T>::A(A<T>&& a)
{
    v = std::move(a.v); // although moving PODs does not make sense in my example
}
```

Now, my **C++11 code** uses the **above C++11 class** as follows:

```
int main()
{
    A<char> a;
    A<float> b(a); // okay
    A<char> c(a); // gcc output is as below:
                 // error: use of deleted function 'constexpr A<char>::A(const A<char>&)'
                 // note: 'constexpr A<char>::A(const A<char>&)' is implicitly declared
                 // as deleted because 'A<char>' declares a move constructor or move
                 // assignment operator
    return 0;
}
```

It gives the error `use of deleted function 'constexpr A<char>::A(const A<char>&)'`.

However, it **compiles and runs properly** when I am **not using any move semantics in the class definition** as below:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    T v;
    A(){};
    template <typename U>
    A(const A<U>& a);
  //  A(A<T>&& a); // removed move ctor
};

template <typename T>
template <typename U>
A<T>::A(const A<U>& a)
{
    v = a.v;
}
```

My questions are:

1. **Why the gcc compiler is treating** the `template <typename U>` in **copy ctor**  differently in the two situations?
2. Why does it **fail to treat typenames** `T == U` in **the presence of move ctor**?
3. Why do I **need to explicitly write yet** another template
   function `template <typename T> A<T>::A(const A<U>& a)` when using
   **move ctor**?

Comment: For starts, `A(const A<U>& a)` is not a copy  constructor.

Comment: @101010: But, it is using the same function when T==U.

Comment: @SMH I believe that the C++ spec specifically says that template functions can't be copy constructors. I think the reason for this is that there's no easy way to determine whether a template type eventually evaluates back to some specific type.

Comment: @templatetypedef Thanks a lot!..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't written a copy constructor. From `[class.copy]` in the C++11 standard:

> A non-template constructor for class X is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type X&, const X&, volatile X& or const volatile X&, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments (8.3.6).

(I see no provision for a *template* constructor to be called a copy constructor)

and consequently

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared implicitly

The difference between the two examples is whether or not you have a move constructor:

> If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (8.4)

Comment: The final piece of the puzzle is that the non-template wins overload resolution.

Comment: @Hurky : I see my mistake. Does that mean I have to define both copy ctor using typename T and also copy function(?) using typename U?

Answer (score 1):

Defining the move constructor disabled the copy constructor. What you want is a *converting constructor*, which as the name implies, converts its argument to the type of the class. If your copy/move constructors don't do anything special, either omit or `default` them. To explain the final piece of your confusion, the reason you can omit the template arguments in your fake copy constructor is because of the *injected class name*. Meaning that wherever you see `A`, it's silently substituted for `A<T>`. I've included it for clarity.

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    T v;
    A() = default;

    template <typename U>
    A<T>(const A<U>& a);

    A(const A<T>& a) = default;
    A(A<T>&& a) = default;
};
```

Comment: I see my mistake. Does that mean I have to define both copy ctor  using typename T and also copy function(or whatever converting constructor) using typename U for explicit user defined ones? I need them to be user-defined as my actual class is more complex.